# Android sqlite distinct with multiple where parameters

Tags: android, sqlite, distinct

I have a table "ActivityMeasurements", from which i would like to get all different "MeasurementAttemptId" values for all "Athlete" values passed in. The problem is that different Athletes can have same MeasurementAttemptId, and with following piece of code i'm getting many duplicates even if "distinct" query is set to true.

Here is my code:

```
List<String> measAttempts = new ArrayList<String>();

    String[] wheres = new String[globalRunnersList.size()];

    String questionMarks = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < globalRunnersList.size(); i++)
    {
        wheres[i] = globalRunnersList.get(i).getAthleteId();
        questionMarks += ",?";
    }
    questionMarks = questionMarks.substring(1);

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, "ActivityMeasurements", new String[] {"ActivityMeasurement _id", "MeasurementAttemptId", "Athlete"},"Athlete IN ("+questionMarks+")", wheres, null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            measAttempts.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("MeasurementAttemptId")));
        }
        while(mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return measAttempts;
```

I know i could just add some code to do this after, but i think there should be another way to do this.

Any help appreciated,

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
public Cursor query (boolean distinct, String table, String[] columns, selection, String[], selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```

instead of

```
public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

and set disctinct parameter to true.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what you are suggesting is exatcly what i did use. My problem was multiple columns for "String columns[]" parameter as i posted in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid me, i found a solution already.

The problem was that my query was for multiple columns:

```
{"ActivityMeasurement _id", "MeasurementAttemptId", "Athlete"}
```

this way every line was different from other, so i got many results.
Then i changed it to just this:

```
{"MeasurementAttemptId"}
```

and this returns wanted results.